# Symfony2: ContextErrorException

Tags: php, symfony

I've been running into a problem when I'm trying to create a list of Movies with specific variable Genre. For example, all Movies with Genre "romance" and so on.

The error is:

```
ContextErrorException: Notice: Undefined index: genre in /(...)/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Persisters/BasicEntityPersister.php
```

Entity Genre looks like this:

```
/**
 * Genre entity.
 *
 */

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Class Genre.
 *
 * @package Model
 * @ORM\Table(name="genre")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\Genre")
 */
class Genre
{
 /**
 * Id.
 *
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(
 *     type="integer",
 *     nullable=false,
 *     options={
 *         "unsigned" = true
 *     }
 * )
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 *
 * @var integer $id
 */
private $id;

/**
 * Name.
 *
 * @ORM\Column(
 *     name="name",
 *     type="string",
 *     length=128,
 *     nullable=false
 * )
 *
 * @var string $name
 */
private $name;

/**
 * Movies array
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(
 *      targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Movie",
 *    mappedBy="genre"
 * )
 */
protected $movies;

/**
 * Add movies.
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Movie $movies Movies
 * 
 * @return mixed
 */
public function addMovie(\AppBundle\Entity\Movie $movies)
{
    $this->movies[] = $movies;
}
/**
 * Remove movies
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Movie $movies Movies
 * 
 * @return mixed
 */
public function removeAnswer(\AppBundle\Entity\Movie $movies)
{
    $this->movies->removeElement($movies);
}
/**
 * Get movies.
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getMovies()
{
    return $this->movies;
}
/**
 * Constructor
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->movies = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}
/**
 * Remove movies
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Movie $movies Movies
 * 
 * @return mixed
 */
public function removeMovie(\AppBundle\Entity\Movie $movies)
{
    $this->movies->removeElement($movies);
}

/**
 * Get Id.
 *
 * @return integer Result
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

public function setId($id)
{
    $this->id = $id;
}

/**
 * Set name.
 *
 * @param string $name Name
 */
public function setName($name)
{
    $this->name = $name;
}

/**
 * Get name.
 *
 * @return string Name
 */
public function getName()
{
    return $this->name;
}
}
```

While movie looks like this:

```
/**
 * Movie entity.
 */

 namespace AppBundle\Entity;

 use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Class Movie.
 *
 * @package Model
 * @ORM\Table(name="movies")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\Movie")
 */
class Movie
{

/**
 * Id.
 *
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(
 *     type="integer",
 *     nullable=false,
 *     options={
 *         "unsigned" = true
 *     }
 * )
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 *
 * @var integer $id
 */
private $id;

/**
 * Title.
 *
 * @ORM\Column(
 *     name="title",
 *     type="string",
 *     length=255,
 *     nullable=false
 * )
 *
 * @var string $title
 */
private $title;

/**
 * Notes.
 *
 * @ORM\Column(
 *     name="notes",
 *     type="text",
 *     nullable=true
 * )
 *
 * @var string $notes
 */
private $notes;

/**
 * Genre array
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Genre")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="genre_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * )
 *
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection $genres
 */
 protected $genres;


/**
 * Constructor.
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->tags = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 * Get id.
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set id.
 *
 * @param integer $id
 */
public function setId($id)
{
    $this->id = $id;
}


/**
 * Set title.
 *
 * @param string $title
 */
public function setTitle($title)
{
    $this->title = $title;
}

/**
 * Get title.
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getTitle()
{
    return $this->title;
}

/**
 * Set notes.
 *
 * @param string $notes
 */
public function setNotes($notes)
{
    $this->notes = $notes;
}

/**
 * Get notes.
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getNotes()
{
    return $this->notes;
}

/**
 * Add genre
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Genre $genres
 * @return Movie
 */
public function addGenre(\AppBundle\Entity\Genre $genres)
{
    $this->genres[] = $genres;

    return $this;
}  

/**
 * Remove genre
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Genre $genres
 */
public function removeGenre(\AppBundle\Entity\Genre $genres)
{
    $this->generes->removeElement($generes);
}  

/**
 * Get genre
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
 */
public function getGenre()
{
    return $this->genres;
}  

/**
 * Set genre
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Genre $genres
 * @return Movie
 */
public function setGenre(\AppBundle\Entity\Genre $genres = null)
{
    $this->genres = $genres;

    return $this;
}
```

And while trying to do this, I use this in GenreController:

```
 public function viewAction(Genre $genre)
{
    if (!$genre) {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException('Genre not found!');
    }

    $movies= $genre->getMovies();

    return $this->templating->renderResponse(
        'AppBundle:Genre:view.html.twig',
        array('genre' => $genre)
    );
}
```

Now every time I try to generate the page, I get a error message:

```
ContextErrorException: Notice: Undefined index: genre in /home/(...)/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Persisters/BasicEntityPersister.php line 1758
```

It's a first time I'm doing something like this, so I'm fully aware it's probably full of errors, but I have no idea where this one is coming from, so it's really hard for me to do anything about it. I would appreciate, if someone would show me my mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

The entity name is **Genre**, but you reference it as **Genere** in some parts of the code

Comment: Yes, that is correct, although this is not the main problem. In my files I have just "genere" even though I know it's technically a misspelling, but I want to work on it later.

Comment: Then may be the $generes variable on the Movies class. On the $movies relationship on Genere class you wrote: mappedBy="genre" in singular although the variabla name is plural

Comment: No, it's not it. Like I said, in my own files the name is always "genere". Here I wanted to change it, so it would look better, bu for some reason, part of generes were changed, while the rest stayed the same. Anyway, it's correct in my files, so this is not the root of the problem.